# Quero guardar um retorno de um função no php dentro de uma variável

Tags: php, funções

Ola,

estou com o seguinte problema,

tenho um codigo em php, onde nele declaro uma função para buscar cep no servidor dos correios, nessa função me retorna um json dependendo do cep que informo.

agora quero guardar ela em uma variavel porém não estou conseguindo, ao gugardar ele exibe o retorno da função sem que eu queira.

como trato isso?

segue a função;

```
function obterLogradouro($cep)
{

$html = simple_curl('http://m.correios.com.br/movel/buscaCepConfirma.do',array(
    'cepEntrada'=>$cep,
    'tipoCep'=>'',
    'cepTemp'=>'',
    'metodo'=>'buscarCep'
));

phpQuery::newDocumentHTML($html, $charset = 'utf-8');
$errCEP= array('erro'=> trim(pq('.erro:eq(0)')->html()));

if(empty($errCEP["erro"])){

    $dados =
    array(
    'logradouro'=> trim(pq('.caixacampobranco .resposta:contains("Logradouro: ") + .respostadestaque:eq(0)')->html()),
    'bairro'=> trim(pq('.caixacampobranco .resposta:contains("Bairro: ") + .respostadestaque:eq(0)')->html()),
    'cidade/uf'=> trim(pq('.caixacampobranco .resposta:contains("Localidade / UF: ") + .respostadestaque:eq(0)')->html()),
    'cep'=> trim(pq('.caixacampobranco .resposta:contains("CEP: ") + .respostadestaque:eq(0)')->html())
    );

    $dados['cidade/uf'] = explode('/',$dados['cidade/uf']);
    $dados['cidade'] = trim($dados['cidade/uf'][0]);
    $dados['uf'] = trim($dados['cidade/uf'][1]);
    unset($dados['cidade/uf']);

    die(json_encode($dados));

}else{

echo "CEP não localizado!!!";

}

}
```

E agora como estou tentando guardar;

```
$dadocep= 91250000;
```

$var=obterLogradouro($dadocep);

mas, ao fazer isso eu quero tratar e não exibir.

obrigado!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Já tentou fazer no lugar do

```
die(json_encode($dados));
```

fazer

```
return json_encode($dados);
```

e no caso de falha

```
return "CEP não localizado!!!";
```

você não está dando o `return` na função por isso sua variável fica vazia;

Comment: Somente complementando a resposta: caso esteja utilizando PHP 7 é possível disparar uma exceção de CEP não encontrado, caso contrário o retorno poderia ser feito como sugere o Fernando ou até mesmo o valor NULL, considerando o tratamento adequado na camada superior.